# AngularJS date picker value in Spring model setter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring, datetime

Using angularJS with Spring- for User object DOB field, using input type date on my view file which is bind with attribute "user.dateOfBirth".

Whenever i select any date it is perfectly fine on view itself , no issue.

```
{{user.dateOfBirth}}
```

As soon as i submit and date setter of my pojo User object is invoked, the value coming is a day behind.

For ex- On AngularJS Ui, displayed value is- Oct 11, 2019 12:00:00 AM which is as per selected date
but on User model- Date setter

```
public void setDateOfBirth(String dateOfBirth) { 
    //Value is coming as 2019-10-10T18:30:00.000Z 
    //which is a day behind the selected value      

    this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
}
```

Comment: That's peculiar. `12:00:00 AM` doesn't exist, maybe `12:00:00 PM`

Comment: well I am using  ```` ng-bind="ctrl.user.dateOfBirth | date: 'medium'" ````

Comment: Also, you seem to send the date as a string, therefore on server side there is no conversion. It displays exactly what you send from client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> //Value is coming as 2019-10-10T18:30:00.000Z 
> //which is a day behind the selected value
> ```

The AngularJS date picker uses the local timezone when parsing the date.

To set the date to UTC, use the `ng-model-options` directive:

```
<input type="date" ng-model="date1"
       ng-model-options="{timezone: 'UTC'}"
/>
```

Then the AngularJS will encode the date as 00:00 hours Zulu instead of 00:00 hours India (which is 18:30 Zulu of the previous day).

For more information, see

- [AngularJS `ng-model-options` Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions#specifying-timezones)